# Array Homework Questions

Tags: java, arrays, logic

Im doing self review for finals this week. I came across these questions about arrays. They are identical questions and they have left me confused. Can someone explain them to me so that I might be able to solve them?

Suppose you have declared an array as follows: num values[4] = 0,0,0,0. Which of following is an allowed operation?

```
a. values[2] = 17 
b. input values [0]
c. values[3] = values[0] + 10
d. all of the above
```

suppose you have declared an array as follows: num values[4] = 0,0,0,0. Which of following is an allowed operation?

```
a. values [4] = 80
b. values[2] = values[4] - values[0]
c. output values [3]
d. all of the above
```

Comment: You should tag this question with the language you're using.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set#Instruction_types

Answer (score 0):

The questions are different in that the indices used are different.  In the first question, the indices used are 2, 0, and 3.  In the second question, the indices are 4, 2, 0, and 3.  The array was declared with 4 values, so are the set of used indices valid in both questions? (Hint: they're not all valid)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you put in the tags that you use java, but the way the questions are stated it doesn't look like java.
I would have expected it to look like this:
int[] number = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
etc

If we continue with java in mind this might help:
1a is possible, this sets the number saved in the 3d slot to 17.
1b I have never seen something like that before so I excpect that it doesn't work.
1c is possible, this places the number in the 1st slot + 10 in the 4th slot.

2a is not possible, because values[4] means the 5th slot (java uses 0 for the first slot) and the array only is 4 big.
2b is not possible, same reason as 2a
2c same as 1b

hope this helps

Comment: I assumed it's Java. The textbook doesn't clealy state Java or C++. The book is Programming Logic and Design.